# Does anyone know what this fantasy script is from?

Tags: story-identification, object-identification

[image]

My friend keeps on writing it, yet he won't tell me where it's from.
He says the third line from the top says : "for what reason."

Comment: [Wingdings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wingdings)? I have no idea but it looks inspired by egyptian writing to me :/

Comment: Looks more like runes.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots I thought that runes were essentially linear.  Very few curves/circles.  I thought the same at the beginning, but just too many curved "letters".

Comment: @FuzzyBoots too inconsistent to be a real set of runes. I recognise some of them, but very few, and there is too much difference between them. This is a ugly mash up of many different alphabets, and I'm going crazy as I can't recall where I already saw the leaf shaped one .\/.

Comment: Runes don't tend to have curved or horizontal lines because they were used when carving onto wood or stone. This language might be based on runic languages but isn't one itself due to the horizontal and curved lines. Not 100% sure though.

Comment: Does not look like Cirth (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cirth).

Comment: The more time I spend on this the more time I'm wondering if your friend just made it up themselves.

Comment: At a guess this is english transliterated into an alphabet that is a mashup of several real alphabets. So techniques to solve a mono-alphabetic cipher should apply. The thing that looks like two Xes is almost certainly a consonant and the vertical rectangle is probably a vowel. Circle with a dot in it is almost certainly 'E'.

Comment: Kinda reminds me of Agents of Shield. Where the people effected couldn't stop writing in the alien language. Is your friend ok? Do we need to call Unit? let us know if they sprout tentacles or something. :)

Comment: So it's just symbol replacement?  (|) is o, triangle with tail is A, etc?

Comment: More suited for the Puzzling site?

Comment: How is this on topic? You call it a "fantasy text" but since it's undecipherable, what basis do you have for saying that it's fantasy or science fiction?

Comment: @user14111 OP's friend implies that it is from a scifi / fantasy work.

Comment: Does your friend happen to be a _Life is Strange_ fan?

Comment: I submitted a [translated version](http://i.imgur.com/sNVMRMU.png) to one of the answers. When you see your friend, tell him a random skull on the internet told you his chalkmanship is atrocious and that "horrible" has two Rs and an E on the end.

Answer (score 141, accepted):

**EDIT: [Adele C. seems to have found the actual language.](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/160840/41144) So go give them some love.**

---

I feel that after pouring over possibly hundreds of fictional languages trying to find an exact match I can confidently say that your friend made the language up on his own. That being said I have spent even more time trying to decipher it and below is what I have so far arrived at.

**"Life is strange why why today for what reason (?)y does this (?)eey happen in (? 'sc' maybe?)hool is hori(?)l (misspelled horrible maybe?) is (?)lor are we not"**

I am fairly confident in most letters though a few are guesses based on letters surrounding them. Based on the content that seems reasonably accurate, I think there might be more to this message that is either scrambled, cut off, or whatever else. My current library of letters can be seen below. Excuse the messiness of it.

[image: letters]

If you can improve upon this, please do.

Comment: Yep...I'm up voting Adele's but gotta up-vote yours for decoding effort!

Comment: You mean 'alphabet', not 'language'.

Comment: @Hurkyl To be more specific, it's script, not alphabet.

Comment: @poepje An alphabet is a type of script, and since this is a simple cypher for the English alphabet, it's also an alphabet.

Comment: @Marq An alpabet is a script based on the Latin or Greek scripts. Runes, Chinese characters, hieroglyphs; they're all scripts but not alphabets.

Comment: @poepje: an alphabet is a script with consonants and vowels. As opposed to syllabaries, abjads (e.g: Hebrew and Arabic, where symbols represent consonants (or, arguably, the class of syllables with a given consonant), and short vowels are represented in modern times via diacritics), abugidas (e.g. Devanagari, Tibetan, where symbols represent syllables with an implied vowel, and can be modified to have a different vowel), pictographic scripts, ideographic scripts, logographic scripts, ...

Comment: @poepje What ninjaij said! See the excellent [omniglot](www.omniglot.com) for more information and examples.

Comment: We need your decoding skills over at [puzzling.se]!

Comment: This is like a considerably less engaging version of Gold Bug by Edgar Allen Poe.

Comment: @ninjalj but the Phoenician alphabet is called an alphabet despite not having vowels!

Comment: @DmitryNarkevich: I've seen it called a proto-alphabet, a consonantary, or an abjad.

Answer (score 356):

[image: Key From Redwall Wiki]
Wow, this takes me back.  This is the [script of the Royal House of Riftgard](http://redwall.wikia.com/wiki/Royal_House_of_Riftgard_Script), from Brian Jacques' [Redwall series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redwall).  Specifically, it is featured in *[Triss](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triss)*.

Here is your friend's message in full:

[image: Translation By Pharap]

Comment: What does it say, I (and possibly others) am too lazy to translate it myself!

Comment: @Edlothiad *LIFE IS STRANGE WHY WHY TODAY FOR WHAT REASON* (first bit)

Comment: @JonClements, You're not the hero we deserve but the hero we need.

Comment: Life is Strange. Why why today. For what reason. Why does this keep happening. School is horrible. Is (whlor?). Are we not.

Comment: Corrected for a couple of spelling errors / words that are cut off from the picture. Can't figure out what that one that really looks like "whlor" is supposed to be though.

Comment: @DisturbedNeo yeah - spent 15 mins trying to think what that is supposed to be and gave up. That's going to bug me the rest of the day.

Comment: Seems like a variant of the [Runic Alphabet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runes#Runic_alphabets)

Comment: @MarkRogers To me, it looks more like an amalgamation of elements from Cyrillic, Phoenician, and Egyptian.  Ah, Redwall.

Comment: Wow! Congratulations on your answer. People must really like this answer: 224 upvotes for a mere 5000 views is pretty impressive.

Comment: Don't know if that helps with deciphering, but the character *w* in *whlor* is written wrongly. There is a vertical stroke on the right end that doesn't belong there.

Comment: @Adamant I think people are reacting to the fact that the "correct" answer is below a "helpful, but not correct" answer (in that it doesn't technically answer the question of "where is this script from"). Of course, that's just because the other answer is accepted, but still.

Comment: Good ol' RHOR. I love the Redwall series :)

Comment: Yep, this is definitely *neater* than the accepted answer. Good job reaching the 3rd highest answer post on SFF.SE.

Comment: Your answer is likely to very shortly become the most-upvoted answer on the site.

Comment: @Adamant- Not sure I deserve it.  I hate to cop to it, but there was very little research involved.  I just read the series religiously as a kid.

Comment: @AdeleC Oh, then I'll call some friends over to downvote and balance it out.  Hahah.  Just kidding …