# What languages are present in this text?

Tags: object-identification

I was working through a test and saw an image with some familiar gibberish in it.

[image]

At first glance, it looks like Aurebesh, the language from Star Wars, but some of the characters don't line up, and a couple look like they're flipped around.  Is there another character set being used here, or is it all just garbage?

Comment: What test is this? Where did you see it?

Comment: This is either too broad with no context / there is nothing to indicate that this is on topic

Comment: It was an online training test.  I looked over it with the Aurebesh map from wookiepedia and saw there were a few letters that are similar,  second line character 4 is a flipped character.  It was just used an example of a fake email. I thought it was off topic, but saw this question: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/160805/does-anyone-know-what-this-fantasy-script-is-from

Comment: It looks somewhat like [Hebrew](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hebrew_alphabet), except that the punctuation indicates that this text flows from left to right.  In the word at bottom right, the fourth character from the left resembles [aleph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aleph).  Maybe this is a collection of characters from various languages.

Comment: You could try [Omniglot](https://www.omniglot.com/conscripts/fictional.htm), but I can't see anything that matches at a glance. But then, I'm basing my glance on font rather than specific letter shape.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because there doesn't appear to be any reason to assume that this is a sci-fi or fantasy language (e.g. as opposed to any other set of random symbols).